# Equipotential Surface in Non conservative electric field

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Is there any equipotential surface in non conservative field or induced electric field produce due to change in magnetic field through a given area

Answer (score 2):

If a field is not conservative, then it can't have an associated potential energy, and therefore you can't define equipotential surfaces.